# How do I expire a session using react-firebaseui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebaseui

Help needed. We are using **react-firebaseui** for our email/password login/signup page in our react.js app. Now I need to expire the session and I don't see how.
I know without firebaseui I would just set the persistence like this

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(() => {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return error
  });
```

But I don't seem to have that option with firebaseui.
This is what I am working with in the Login component:

```
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
const Login = () => {
    const uiConfig = {
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInSuccessUrl: '/',
        signInOptions: [
            firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
    }

    return <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
}
```

The login/signup works perfectly, but I don't see a way to expire it. I tried using the callbacks within the uiConfig, but I could not make it work.

package.js

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-firebaseui": "^4.1.0",
```

Any thoughts How I could do it without tossing out the firebaseui component and build it from scratch?
Thank you